# Action cannot be processed due to ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: web-services, wshttpbinding, contract, mismatch

I am trying to get a simple webservice running that sends emails out upon being triggered but I am getting the following error when trying to set it up:

**The message with Action 'localhost/IFabricService/StartMailRun' cannot be processed at the receiver, due  to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).'.**

My service is coded as follows:

```
namespace Project.Fabric
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFabricService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void StartMailRun(int id, string customerGuid);

}


// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

}

This is called from within a class library that called Project.Biz with the file being called EmailBiz.cs using 
the following code:

```
public void StartEmailRun(int id)
    {
        WS2007HttpBinding myBinding = new WS2007HttpBinding();
        myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        myBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;

        // Create the endpoint address.
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("https://fabric.metalearning.net/FabricService.svc");

        // Create the client.                       
        MetaLearning.Fabric.Console.ServiceReference1.FabricServiceClient svc = new MetaLearning.Fabric.Console.ServiceReference1.FabricServiceClient(myBinding, ea);


        // Specify a certificate to use for authenticating the client.
        svc.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
        StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
        StoreName.My,
        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
        "thumbprinthere");

        // Begin using the client.
        try
        {
            svc.Open();
            //this will need changed to include correct string of GUID and correct ID for email campaign.
            svc.StartMailRun(id, "a67f8076-82c6-427c-ac34-fb34aee59e0b");
            System.Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the client.
            svc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }  
    }
```

The web.config of the Fabric service looks as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceCredentialsBehaviour" name="MetaLearning.Fabric.FabricService">
    <endpoint binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IFabricService" name="SecuredByClientCertificate" contract="MetaLearning.Fabric.IFabricService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <ws2007HttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IFabricService">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    <!--<security mode="Transport"> 
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/> 
      <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>--> 
    </binding>
  </ws2007HttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceCredentialsBehaviour">
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="thumbprinthere" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="LocalMachine" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="ws2007HttpBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
```

Can anyone see what I am overlooking that would be causing this issue?